# The definition of the infinite sum of ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $\{I_{\beta}\}_{\beta \in B}$ in $R$, with $\beta$ a infinite set. Is  $$\sum_{\beta \in B} I_{\beta}=\{f_1+\cdots+f_r:f_j \in I_{\beta_j} \mbox{ for some } I_{\beta_j}\}\ ?$$ I feel confused because by this description, every element in $\sum_{\beta \in B} I_{\beta}$ is a finite sum, but $\sum_{\beta \in B} I_{\beta}$ is a infinite sum of ideals. Also I don't find a definition of $\sum_{\beta \in B} I_{\beta}$, can you tell me what the definition is?

Comment: You can define the sum also as the smallest ideal that contain all $I_\beta$. Where smallest = intersection of all suitable ideals.

Comment: Your definition is correct. Note that even your element is a finite sum of elements, there is no bound of how many summands could have your element.

Comment: You can think of the infinite sum of ideals as the smallest ideal that contains all of the ideals. Ideals need to only be closed under binary sums, so there is no way to get infinite sums in an ideal. (Indeed, there is not definition of infinite sums, in the general ring.)